# Updating array without mutating it

Tags: react-native

From what I understand you should never mutate an object inside an array directly in react native, however say that I want to update a specific object inside an array - but still keep the same index nr and position of that object, `selectedGoal` in this case. How would I do that?

Now it keeps adding it to the end, which makes the item always appear in the end when it's manipulated.

```
const [goals, setGoals] = useState([])

...other code here...

    const updatedGoal = [...goals.filter(goal=>goal.id !== selectedGoal.id), selectedGoal]
    setGoals(updatedGoal)
```

**example of nested array:**

```
const addTodoToGoal = (todo, goalListId) =>{
    const relevantList = goals.find(list=> list.id === goalListId) 
    relevantList.todos.push(todo)                                  
    const goalsMinusRelevantList = goals.filter((list)=>list.id !== goalListId)  
    const newGoals=[...goalsMinusRelevantList, relevantList]
    setGoals(newGoals)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering with state:

```js
const updatedGoal = goals.filter(item => item.id === id);
setGoals(updatedGoal);
```

You can use map instead and a if ternary to return the new object or the old one instead if you want to change something inside the list:

```js
const updatedGoal = goals.map(item => item.id === id ? {} : item);
setGoals(updatedGoal);
```

You can also pass the new value directly inside the state:

```js
setGoals(prev => prev.map(item => item.id === id ? {} : item));
```

Filtering with same logic:

```js
setGoals(prev => prev.filter(item => item.id === id));
```

EDIT

In your code case, your are filtering the the goals that not match the id and putting the selectedGoal at the end of the list:

```js
const updatedGoal = [...goals.filter(goal=>goal.id !== selectedGoal.id), selectedGoal]
```

If you want to update a specific item you should try the **map** keyword like my example, inside the map you can match the selectedId and change the object, something like this:

```js
const updatedGoal = goals.map(item => item.id === selectedGoal.id
? ({
   ...item, // this keep attributes you dont want to change
   done: true, // here you can change other attributes
   foo: "bar",
  })
: item);
```

Comment: ahh thank you for your answer! I'm still a bit new to react native so I don't get the logic 100% in your examples, do you think you could help me in my specific case with applying the code if you have the time? (tell me if I need to add more of my code in the edit)

Comment: I editted the post, see if helps you and let me know

Comment: Can I ask one more question if you have time, if I want to manipulate a nested array (say in your example, if instead of done it's a new list array, and I want to add a new object into that array or change something in it. How would I access it? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: You can use nested map aswell to change things, in theory that's not related with React States, that's just array and objects manipulation with javascript. The only thing that is necessary to update the state like it should is keeping the indexes in the right place.

Here a little cheatsheet with updating objects and array for react:

https://dev.to/andyrewlee/cheat-sheet-for-updating-objects-and-arrays-in-react-state-48np

Comment: I can't get the nested array to work with the same logic as you showed me before, I added my current logic in the code, could you please show me if you have the time?

Comment: You can send me on Discord Andore#0773, I'll be happy to help you